# How to test / extract different mime parts of Mail::Message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

When testing a multipart mail message in rails 3, is there a built-in way to extract the different parts (text/html, text/plain, etc) and then test those

I've hacked together something quickly for use in my test: https://gist.github.com/2899995, but would prefer to use existing rails code if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `email.html_part` and `email.text_part` to get the two parts and `email.html_part.body` and `email.text_part.body` to get the text. You can also validate the email is multipart with `email.multipart?`

The `email.parts` method will give you all the parts of the message:
https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb